# `UriComponentsBuilder` wierd behaviour in multiple path calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

If I look into the source code of `UriComponentsBuilder`, it looks like it is collecting all paths that will eventually be used to create final path.

```
    @Override
    public UriComponentsBuilder path(String path) {
        this.pathBuilder.addPath(path);
        resetSchemeSpecificPart();
        return this;
    }
```

However, based on this assumption I wrote this test which fails. It seems like that `UriComponentsBuilder` combines them as one simple path instead of separating it by `/`.

```java
  @Test
  public void testFunctioning(){

    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
        .path("one")
        .path("two")
        .path("three")
        .toUriString();

    assertEquals("one/two/three", url);

  }
```

```
    Expected :one/two/three
    Actual   :onetwothree
```

Is my understanding itself regarding behaviour of `UriComponentsBuilder` is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `pathSegment(String... segment)`, so something like:

```java
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .pathSegment("one", "two", "three")
                .toUriString();
```

Which is outputting `/one/two/three`.